# Добавить в массив ключи и значения из другого массива

Tags: php, массивы

Не могу решить проблему, я не так долго занимаюсь PHP, это мой первый язык програмирования. Путем манипуляций получаю два массива с нужными мне ключами, первый это шаблон кнопок на телефоне:

```
$pbt = [
    ['buttonNumber' => '1', 'feature' => 'Line'],
    ['buttonNumber' => '2', 'feature' => 'Line'],
    ['buttonNumber' => '3', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '', 'blfDest' => '', 'blfFeature' => ''],
    ['buttonNumber' => '4', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '', 'blfDest' => '', 'blfFeature' => ''],
    ['buttonNumber' => '5', 'feature' => 'Service URL'],
    ['buttonNumber' => '6', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '', 'blfDest' => '', 'blfFeature' => ''],
    ['buttonNumber' => '7', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '', 'blfDest' => '', 'blfFeature' => ''],
    ['buttonNumber' => '8', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '', 'blfDest' => '', 'blfFeature' => ''],
    ['buttonNumber' => '9', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '', 'blfDest' => '', 'blfFeature' => ''],
    ['buttonNumber' => '10', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '', 'blfDest' => '', 'blfFeature' => ''],
    ['buttonNumber' => '11', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '', 'blfDest' => '', 'blfFeature' => ''],
    ['buttonNumber' => '12', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '', 'blfDest' => '', 'blfFeature' => ''],
    ['buttonNumber' => '13', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '', 'blfDest' => '', 'blfFeature' => ''],
    ['buttonNumber' => '14', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '', 'blfDest' => '', 'blfFeature' => ''],
    ['buttonNumber' => '15', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '', 'blfDest' => '', 'blfFeature' => ''],
    ['buttonNumber' => '16', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '', 'blfDest' => '', 'blfFeature' => ''],
    ['buttonNumber' => '17', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '', 'blfDest' => '', 'blfFeature' => ''],
    ['buttonNumber' => '18', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '', 'blfDest' => '', 'blfFeature' => ''],
];
```

второй, это список кнопок, которые должны вставляться в массив $pbt если эта пара истина 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF'

```
$blf = [
    ['blfButton' => '1', 'blfLabel' => 'Сергей', 'blfDest' => '1410', 'blfFeature' => 'PickUp'],
    ['blfButton' => '2', 'blfLabel' => 'Иван', 'blfDest' => '1101', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],
    ['blfButton' => '3', 'blfLabel' => 'Сергей', 'blfDest' => '1299', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],
    ['blfButton' => '5', 'blfLabel' => 'Андрей', 'blfDest' => '3256', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],
    ['blfButton' => '6', 'blfLabel' => 'Александр', 'blfDest' => '1266', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],
    ['blfButton' => '10', 'blfLabel' => 'Оксана', 'blfDest' => '1119', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],
    ['blfButton' => '11', 'blfLabel' => 'Елена', 'blfDest' => '1167', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],
    ['blfButton' => '12', 'blfLabel' => 'Виктория', 'blfDest' => '1265', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],
    ['blfButton' => '13', 'blfLabel' => 'Сергей', 'blfDest' => '1234', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],
    ['blfButton' => '14', 'blfLabel' => 'Виктор', 'blfDest' => '1253', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],
    ['blfButton' => '15', 'blfLabel' => 'Михаил', 'blfDest' => '1233', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],
];
```

Как вы видите ['blfButton']  4,7,8,9, пропущены, потому, что пользователь не стал настраивать 'blfDest' на 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', его право.

```
['blfButton' => '6', 'blfLabel' => 'Александр', 'blfDest' => '1266', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],
['blfButton' => '10', 'blfLabel' => 'Оксана', 'blfDest' => '1119', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],
```

Мне надо, что бы каким то волшебным способом (я третий день пробую разные варианты, в основном это комбинации foreach с if и array_key_exists) значения ключей $blf подставлялись в $pbt следующим образом:

```
$pbt = [
    ['buttonNumber' => '1', 'feature' => 'Line'],
    ['buttonNumber' => '2', 'feature' => 'Line'],
    ['buttonNumber' => '3', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => 'Сергей', 'blfDest' => '1410', 'blfFeature' => 'PickUp'],      //'blfButton' => '1'
    ['buttonNumber' => '4', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'Иван', 'blfDest' => '1101', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],                //'blfButton' => '2'
    ['buttonNumber' => '5', 'feature' => 'Service URL'],
    ['buttonNumber' => '6', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => 'Сергей', 'blfDest' => '1299', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],        //'blfButton' => '3'
    ['buttonNumber' => '7', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '------', 'blfDest' => '------', 'blfFeature' => '------'],    //'blfButton' => '4' не настроена, вставить '------'
    ['buttonNumber' => '8', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => 'Андрей', 'blfDest' => '3256', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],        //'blfButton' => '5'
    ['buttonNumber' => '9', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => 'Александр', 'blfDest' => '1266', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],     //'blfButton' => '6'
    ['buttonNumber' => '10', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '------', 'blfDest' => '------', 'blfFeature' => '------'],   //'blfButton' => '7' не настроена, вставить '------'
    ['buttonNumber' => '11', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '------', 'blfDest' => '------', 'blfFeature' => '------'],   //'blfButton' => '8' не настроена, вставить '------'
    ['buttonNumber' => '12', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => '------', 'blfDest' => '------', 'blfFeature' => '------'],   //'blfButton' => '9' не настроена, вставить '------'
    ['buttonNumber' => '13', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => 'Оксана', 'blfDest' => '1119', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],       //'blfButton' => '10'
    ['buttonNumber' => '14', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => 'Елена', 'blfDest' => '1167', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],        //'blfButton' => '11'
    ['buttonNumber' => '15', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => 'Виктория', 'blfDest' => '1265', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],     //'blfButton' => '12'
    ['buttonNumber' => '16', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => 'Сергей', 'blfDest' => '1234', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],       //'blfButton' => '13'
    ['buttonNumber' => '17', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => 'Виктор', 'blfDest' => '1253', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],       //'blfButton' => '14'
    ['buttonNumber' => '18', 'feature' => 'Speed Dial BLF', 'blfLabel' => 'Михаил', 'blfDest' => '1233', 'blfFeature' => 'None'],       //'blfButton' => '15'
];
```

пробовал array_merge, но он добавляет все в конец массива $pbt, array_replase просто заменяет все, но не добавляет. Возможно тут надо использовать callback функцию, но у меня пока это не получается (.

Comment: https://www.php.net/array_replace

Comment: u_mulder вы как всегда подсказываете интересные решения! Вроде то, что нужно, завтра буду пробовать, благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$feature = 'Speed Dial BLF';
$countBLF = array_count_values(array_column($pbt, 'feature'))[$feature];

foreach ($busyLampFields as $key => $value) {
    $item = $value['index']; // первый ключ массива единица, не нуль!
 //   $item = $key;
    $blf[$item]['blfButton'] = $value['index'] == NULL ? "None" : $value['index'];
    $blf[$item]['blfLabel'] = $value['label'] == NULL ? "None" : $value['label'];
    $blf[$item]['blfDest'] = $value['blfDest'] == NULL ? "None" : $value['blfDest'];
    $blf[$item]['blfFeature'] = $value['associatedBlfSdFeatures'] == NULL ? "None" : $value['associatedBlfSdFeatures']['feature'];  
}

for ($i = 1; $i < ($countBLF + 1); $i++) {
    if (!array_key_exists($i, $blf)) {
        $blf[$i]['blfButton'] = $i;
        $blf[$i]['blfLabel'] = '------';
        $blf[$i]['blfDest'] = '------';
        $blf[$i]['blfFeature'] = '------';
    }
}

ksort($resultBLF);

$i = 1;
foreach ($pbt as $keyA => $valueA) {    
    $item = $keyA;
    foreach ($valueA as $keyB => $valueB) {
        if ($valueB == 'Speed Dial BLF')   {            
//            echo "$keyA - $keyB - $valueB\n";
            $pbt[$keyA]['blfLabel'] = $blf[$i]['blfLabel'];
            $pbt[$keyA]['blfDest'] = $blf[$i]['blfDest'];
            $pbt[$keyA]['blfFeature'] = $blf[$i]['blfFeature'];
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```